# Querying a PostgreSQL multi-dimensional array data type in Rails 4

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql

I am using a PostgreSQL multi-dimensional array to mimic an array of hashes, and I am looking for a way to locate a record by a key-value pair in that array like e.g ["key1","value1"]. An example array is:

[ ["key1","value1"], ["key2","value2"] ]

The keys are in my case languages and a key may occur more than once.

Is there an efficient way to locate a record by a key-value pair using a PostgreSQL index with Rails 4?

Edit: fixed typo

Comment: can you use extensions? then look on Hstore extension - it is exactly what you want - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766300/hstore-and-rails

Comment: I looked at Hstore, but as Craig says it only supports single-level keys and due to key collision I would need to return an array for a value like e.g { "key1" => ["value1", "value2"] }.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for looking for a convoluted storage solution instead of database fields and tables?

Comment: Denis: I have a table that must be auditable, and that also need slugs per locale. I am trying to create a slugging library that does not need extra tables to simplify interactions with the audit requirement, but it might be a blind alley.

Comment: "slug"? I don't understand how that word applies in this context. I agree with Denis that a simple two-level table relationship would be a good option here.

Comment: Craig, I added too much unrelated context. I have considered a two-level table relationship as an alternative and it might be the best solution after all, but experimented with this solution in an attempt to simplify the code for the audit-ability requirement.

Comment: @AndreasSæbjørnsen What does single-field give you that a two-level table doesn't in audit terms? Either way, you have a transaction that adds a change or set of changes to an audit table using a trigger when the table changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am using a PostgreSQL multi-dimensional array to mimic an array of hashes

Those two things aren't really all that similar, and I wouldn't recommend attempting to use multidimensional arrays to model nested hashes.

Pavel is quite right that [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) is probably a lot closer to what you want, and it's indexable too. However, the current version of hstore (in Pg 9.3 and older) supports only single-level keys; it's a dictionary/hash that can contain only scalar string values. A planned enhancement to hstore for PostgreSQL 9.4 will hopefully bring multi-level nesting and JSON syntax compatibility.

### Ordinary tables

You can model arbitrary-depth key/value chains(and trees/graphs) using edgelists and recursive CTEs, but this probably rather more complexity than you really want.

If you only need a fixed two-level key/value list, simply use a table that lists both key levels:

```
CREATE TABLE twolevel(key1 text, key2 text, thevalue text not null, PRIMARY KEY(key1,key2));
```

This lets you constrain against duplicate key pairs, which is nice.

You can also use two tables with a foreign key relationship between them. This gives you cascade deletes if you want, so removing a top level key removes all sub-level keys and associated values. It's easy enough to do that with the single-table approach, though.

Use one of these two approaches unless you have good reasons to do otherwise.

### Hstore as text

Until the extended hstore is available, one option would be to store *text representations* of nested hstore fields. This is not pretty or efficient, but it's probably better than trying to search a multidimensional array.

```
CREATE TABLE nested_hstore(id integer, blah hstore);

insert into nested_hstore(id, blah) values 
(1, hstore( ARRAY['key1','key2'], ARRAY['"key1.1"=>"value1.1", "key1.2"=>"value1.2"', '"key2.1"=>"value2.1", "key2.2"=>"value2.2"']::hstore[]::text[]));
```

Test:

```
regress=> select (blah->'key1')::hstore->'key1.1' from nested_hstore ;
 ?column? 
----------
 value1.1
(1 row)
```

Because the hstore must be parsed each time it's not going to be super-fast, and you won't get the usual indexing benefits on the second level. Still, it's an option if you really genuinely need two-level hashes in fields.

### Tables of hstore values

You can combine these two quite reasonably.

```
CREATE TABLE twolevel(key1 text, level2keyvalues hstore);
```

It seems pretty ugly to me, though; I'd prefer to be consistent one way or the other.

### SQL/XML

Another option is to use SQL/XML, which you can index along arbitrary XPATH expressions. Again, this seems a bit too complicated.

Comment: It is hard for me to make an informed choice about EdgeLists and recursive CTEs since I do not have much experience with them. However, you are correct that it seems like an undesirable solution because of its complexity. Maybe I am stuck using multiple arrays, one for each language? That is also not desirable.

Comment: @AndreasSæbjørnsen Added some detail. Basically I think you should probably just use an ordinary table for this.

Comment: I ended up using a more traditional schema design as you suggested. It does not seem like the current implementation of the hstore and array feature is that useful in this context.

Comment: @AndreasSæbjørnsen I tend to agree. If the v2 hstore work that supports nesting and json syntax goes well then hopefully that'll change, maybe in 9.5...